# Select different elements with wrapAll — jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to wrap both a `h1` tag and multiple `p` tags into one `div` using jQuery wrapAll.

Here is my HTML:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
<div class="img"></div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('h1').wrapAll('<div class="first-col" />');
$('.img').wrapAll('<div class="second-col" />');
```

And a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SWu4u/1/).

At the moment, I can only wrap around the `h1` tag, or both the `h1` and `p` tags separately. I want them both in the one `first-col` div.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
$('h1').nextUntil('div.img').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="first-col" />');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q8Tv9/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to just add p inside the selector:

```
$('.postwrap').each(function(){
    $(this).find('h1, p').wrapAll('<div class="first-col" />');
    $(this).find('.img').wrapAll('<div class="second-col" />');
});
```

Comment: That works great. But when I have multiple the tags in multiple wrappers, it seems to get messed up. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/SWu4u/2/. I'm trying to get them wrapped in each `postwrap`.

Comment: You are a beautiful specimen.